# Is it possible to mount an NFS partition with a label?

Tags: nfs

I export 3 directories via NFS (pisces:/media/music, pisces:/media/video, pisces:/media/photo) that I mount individually. Currently, they all appear on my (Ubuntu) Gnome desktop as 'pisces', which is less than useful.

The doc seems to indicate that the `-LABEL` switch isn't supported for NFS `mount`; is there some other way of labeling the mounts?

The directories are mounted using `/etc/fstab` (unfortunately I don't have access to that machine right now, and can't remember the options; it is pretty close to the defaults though).

ta,
-- peter

Comment: How do you mount them? Do you have them in your /etc/fstab? Cause if I mount my NFS shares at home to for example /media/audio/ it shows up as "audio" in GNOME.

Comment: I'm having a headslap moment here now ... I'm using `mount pisces:/media/music ~/Music/pisces` (note the machine and folder names are the same) for all ; hence my confusion. Apologies for the noise.

Comment: @nwahmaet - why don't you re-compose this as an answer to your original question, then someone can upvote it, and we can have an answer!

Answer (score 1):

As far as /etc/fstab is concerned, apart from LABEL tags(variables) -- (which are generally for local disks/filesystems) it can also accept UUID identifier. So, in theory  UUID can work for NFS mounts. (UUID should be generated for nfs directory for example nfsserver:/exportdir).

Although, I have not seen people using Labels nor UUIDs for NFS mounts in /etc/fstab.
Instead, the better alternative approach has always been to use automounter or amd.

Answer (score 0):

Per gabe's suggestion above,  answering with my comment ...

I'm having a headslap moment here now ... I'm using mount pisces:/media/music ~/Music/pisces (note the machine and folder names are the same) for all ; hence my confusion. Apologies for the noise.